# Doctrine setter method best practice for paired API call

Tags: php, api, doctrine-orm

I have a table that tracks a customer's status as stored in a third party database.  My table should only be updated when I can successfully update the other database via an API call.

When using Doctrine, is it a bad practice to add the API call into the setter method in my entity class?  For example:

```
public function setCustomerStatus( $cusotmerStatus )
{
   $api = new externalApi();
   if( $api->updateStatus( $customerStatus ) )
   {
      $this->customerStatus = $customerStatus;
   }
   else
   {
      return 'Could not update customer status';
   }
}
```

Comment: I would think you would want to call it on save() and not on set().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an Entity field that can only be set under a certain condition, you have two options; either make the check before the update:

```
if($api->updateStatus($customerStatus){
    $entity->setCustomerStatus($customerStatus);
}
```

Or, make the check within the Entity, such as you have done in the set method. The advantage of containing it within the set method is that you don't leave room for error; unfamiliar developers may not know to run the check prior to calling the set method, or you just may forget. Therefore, if you can guarantee the check need always be made, I prefer the option you have chosen